# Summation of difference between matrix elements

Tags: matrix, matlab

I am in the process of building a function in MATLAB. As a part of it I have to calculate differences between elements in two matrices and sum them up.

Let me explain considering two matrices,

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

and

```
7 8 9 10 11 12
19 20 21 22 23 24
```

The calculations in the first row - only four elements in both matrices are considered at once (zero indicates padding):

```
    (1-8)+(2-9)+(3-10)+(4-11): This replaces 1 in initial matrix.
    (2-9)+(3-10)+(4-11)+(5-12): This replaces 2 in initial matrix.
    (3-10)+(4-11)+(5-12)+(6-0): This replaces 3 in initial matrix.
    (4-11)+(5-12)+(6-0)+(0-0): This replaces 4 in initial matrix. And so on
```

I am unable to decide how to code this in MATLAB. How do I do it?

I use the following equation.

[image: Equation]

Here `i` ranges from `1` to `n(h)`, `n(h)`, the number of distant pairs. It depends on the lag distance chosen. So if I choose a lag distance of `1`, `n(h)` will be `the number of elements - 1`.

When I use a 7 X 7 window, considering the central value, n(h) = 4 - 1 = 3 which is the case here.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: That still isn't a question. It is a statement with a question mark at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was rather obvious.

Comment: The computed example you show doesn't seem to agree with the equation. Where is the squaring?

Comment: @talonmies, squaring steps are rather easy to implement. So I just wanted to know how to code for the part inside the brackets.

Comment: So why not just ask that question then? The key to getting useful answers is to ask clear, unambiguous questions.

Comment: @talonmies, I have removed it and also made changes to question as I had misinterpreted my requirements earlier.

Comment: Why did you remove the equation? Is it no longer valid? If so, can you post the correct equation? Also, isn't this only a slight modification of your earlier question? As I can see from your questions, you're not making an effort to do the programming, instead relying on SO to do the coding for you.

Comment: @yoda, I agree I relied to good extent on SO. Its only because what takes me several hours/days sometimes are answered in minutes at SO due to member's expertise. I removed the equation since I was partially asked to do so. You can see that in earlier comments.

Comment: @Chethan: I don't entirely disagree with using SO for that purpose _some of the time_. It's only when a pattern emerges, that it's problematic.

Comment: @Chethan: I think what talonmies was referring to was that your example did not conform to the equation. I would've rather left the equation and improved the example than the other way round. It's easier for people to think & program when there's an equation, rather than having to figure out the pattern from an example.

Comment: @yoda, you are right. In fact I started learning MATLAB from scratch for my academic project just two months back. As a beginner in programming I find it hard to implement rather complex functions. But I do give a try before asking questions here and though I work on large satellite images I make it a point to make my question simple and explain it in terms of small matrices.

Comment: @chethan: SO is a perfectly good place to ask questions and learn MATLAB. Your example size is good. "squaring steps are rather easy to implement"... I guess if you kept the example size the same, but simply improved it to include the squaring, so that it matched the equation, it will be clear.

Comment: @yoda, I could do that but to make it clear how only 4 elements are considered I increased the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the circshfit() function:

```
a = [1 2 3 4; 9 10 11 12];
b = [5 6 7 8; 12 14 15 16];

for k = 1:3
    b = circshift(b, [0 -1]);
    b(:, end) = 0;

    diff = sum(a - b, 2)
end
```